# UIFont initialiser returns <uninitialized> object and crashes the app

Tags: ios, swift, uifont, nsmutableattributedstring, uifontdescriptor

My iOS app is crashing on iOS 8.2 and working perfectly on iOS 9 and above.
When I checked the crash log, the following function causes the crash (Written in the `NSMutableAttributedString` extension)

```
func changeFont(font: UIFont, range : NSRange, keepFontSize: Bool = false)
{
    let traits     = font.fontDescriptor().symbolicTraits
    let descriptor = baseDescriptor.fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits(traits)

    let newFont    = UIFont(descriptor: descriptor, size: keepFontSize ? descriptor.pointSize : baseDescriptor.pointSize)

    self.removeAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, range: range)
    self.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: newFont, range: range) // <- Crash happens here
}
```

**Crash Log**

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   'NSConcreteMutableAttributedString addAttribute:value:range:: nil
>   value'

When I debugged and logged the variables used in that function, the `descriptor` & `newFont` both shown as `<uninitialized>`

```
(lldb) po traits
▿ UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits
  - rawValue : 268435458            

(lldb) po baseDescriptor
UICTFontDescriptor <0x7fc075b574c0> = {
    NSFontNameAttribute = CenturyGothic;
    NSFontSizeAttribute = 14;
}

(lldb) po descriptor
 <uninitialized>

(lldb) po keepFontSize
true

(lldb) po newFont
 <uninitialized>
```

I can't use `if let` or `newFont != nil` check here, because both will throw an error saying "*UIFont won't be nil*".
How can I fix this crash ? (Or How can I check an object is initialized or not ?) I'm really stuck on this issue, since majority of my users still use iOS 8.

Comment: NSAttributedString ? its not mutable

Comment: @WilsonXJ: Sorry, that was a typo. Actually it is `NSMutableAttributedString`

Comment: what is baseDescriptor， it can be nil ? or other situations

Comment: @WilsonXJ: Please check the `po` debug logs. It is not nil, it is a UIFontDescriptor object

Comment: i found this , maybe the api error <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25977207/font-descriptor-returns-nil-in-ios-8>